# Make a custom view to support change LayoutParams programmatically

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am using a custom view [lyricView](https://github.com/WuLiFei/LyricViewDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mariostudio/lyricviewdemo/LyricView.java) in FrameLayout. It works well in normal case:

[image]

For some reason, I want the lyricview can be show in two size, single line size and fullscreen size.I register a OnClickListener on FrameLayout so user can switch between two size by click on window. So I try to change the LayoutParams in program。

**before click(single line mode)**

- layout file

  ```
  <io.hefuyi.listener.widget.LyricView
  android:id="@+id/lyric_view"
  android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="32dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:visibility="visible"/>
  ```
- the lyric works well

[image]

**after click(fullscreen mode)**

- code segment

  ```
                          FrameLayout.LayoutParams lyricLayout = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) lyricView.getLayoutParams();
                          lyricLayout.height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                          lyricLayout.topMargin = DensityUtil.dip2px(mContext, 55);
                          lyricLayout.bottomMargin = iconContainer.getHeight();
                          lyricView.setLayoutParams(lyricLayout);
                          isLyricFullScreen = true;
  ```
- change layoutparameters not work

[image]

Obviously, I fail to change the lyricview layout fail, because the lyric will be draw in the center of screen if it works.

So,how to make the [lyricView](https://github.com/WuLiFei/LyricViewDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mariostudio/lyricviewdemo/LyricView.java) to support change LayoutParams programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. I notice that in xml you have set height of 32dp to the lyric view and in program you are changing Layout params of frame layout. Please change the Layout Params of lyric view not frame layout because Lyric view's height is still 32 dp.
2. If it doesn't work try calling `requestLayout()` on lyric view in program.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `iconContainer.getHeight()`

Are you sure this line produces the height of the certain view? If this piece of code runs before `iconContainer` laid out (which is the most probable case), you will get 0 for `getHeight`.

If this is the issue, you should add a `GlobalLayoutChangeListener` to the `viewTreeObserver` of `iconContainer`, get height in the listener and use that height.